# Pyinstaller exe APPCRASH Error with ntdll.dll in .exe on Windows 7

Tags: debugging, dll, windows-7, pyinstaller, application-error

I have used `pyinstaller` to make the exe file. I am experiencing an issue with an application on Windows 7, and I need some help diagnosing the problem.

The application is DataPilotSetup.exe (version 1.0.0.0), and it crashes on startup with an APPCRASH error. The faulting module according to the problem details is ntdll.dll.

```
Here are the problem details:
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: DataPilotSetup.exe
  Application Version: 1.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp: 648cbec2
  Fault Module Name: ntdll.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.24214
  Fault Module Timestamp: 5b626f7c
  Exception Code: c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00022302
  OS Version: 6.1.71.0.256.1
  Locale ID: 1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ada78882e789
```

**On my other windows 7 system the error showed up as missing `api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll` which i resolved by copypasting them into my `system32` & `sysWOW64`, but it didn't resolve the problem.**

This is the pyinstaller command i use --

```
pyinstaller --hidden-import "numpy.core._dtype_ctypes" --hidden-import "canmatrix.formats" --hidden-import "canmatrix.formats.dbc" --hidden-import "canmatrix.formats.arxml" --hidden-import "asammdf.blocks.cutils" --hidden-import "psutil" --additional-hooks-dir=hooks --onefile --noconsole --splash "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBDS\DataPilot\img\splashscreen.png" --icon "C:/Program Files/Airforce_Application/Airforce/img/ico.ico" --uac-admin --name "DataPilot" python.py
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for what to try next, or any insights into what might be causing the crash? Any help would be greatly appreciated.